# Eclipse gives "invalid mapping type for this relationship" error for the relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i defined a one to one relationship between my two entities. (EntHesaplasma and EntHesaplasmaek) In the enthesaplasma entity, relation annotions are added to getEntHesaplasmaek method.

```
public class EntHesaplasma implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "hesaplasmaid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getHesaplasmaid() {
       return hesaplasmaid;
    }

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="carihareketid",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public EntHesaplasmaek getEnthesaplasmaek() {
        return enthesaplasmaek;
    }

    public void setEnthesaplasmaek(EntHesaplasmaek enthesaplasmaek) {
        this.enthesaplasmaek = enthesaplasmaek;
    }
```

In the other entity (Enthesaplasmaek class) the relationship is defined as below.

```
public class EntHesaplasmaek implements Serializable{

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name = "hesaplasmaekid", unique = true, nullable = false)
     public Integer getHesaplasmaekid() {
        return hesaplasmaekid;
     }

     ...

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="enthesaplasmaek")
    public EntHesaplasma getEnthesaplasma() {
        return enthesaplasma;
    }
    public void setEnthesaplasma(EntHesaplasma enthesaplasma) {
        this.enthesaplasma = enthesaplasma;
    }
```

but eclipse ide gives an error (invalid mapping type for this relationship) as seen below.

[image: error]

but the application runs with no problem. is there any error here ?

Comment: Does the error disapear when you remove `insertable=false, updatable=false` from the mapping of `getEnthesaplasmaek`? Basically, with your current mappings, it is not possible to make a new association between `EntHesaplasma` and `EntHesaplasmaek`.

Comment: You can do it with native query of course or changing data in the database out of Hibernate of course. It is fine if it really is your use case, I'm just wondering whether it is that that the Eclipse is complaining about.

Comment: yes, eclipse is complaining it. the program and the hibernate work with no problem

Comment: got the same (eclipse) display issue with hibernate 5.4.27 though its working fine.