# Hibernate 3.2.6 / JPA: In attribute 'X', the "mapped by" attribute 'Y' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I have this class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_APPLICATION")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqAPPLICATION", sequenceName = "SEQ_APPLICATION", allocationSize = 1)

public class Application implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<Service>(0);

    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "application", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @OrderBy("id")
    public Set<Service> getServices() {
        return this.services;
    }
..
}
```

and this other one:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_SERVICE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqSERVICE", sequenceName = "SEQ_SERVICE")
public class Service extends ItemBase implements java.io.Serializable {

private Application application;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION", nullable = false)
    public Application getApplication() {
        return this.application;
    }

    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }
..
}
```

But in my Eclipse Version: Mars.2 (4.5.2) editor I have this error

**In attribute 'services', the "mapped by" attribute 'application' has an invalid 
mapping type for this relationship.**

Refreshing and cleaning my project does not help.

This is my JPA eclipse validator

[image]

Comment: Eclipse complains unnecessarily. hibernate should function fine. Try refreshing your project and updating the list of classes in the persistence.xml. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319106/eclipse-gives-invalid-mapping-type-for-this-relationship-error-for-the-relatio

Comment: I don't have any class defined in the persistence.xml

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this, just for completeness?